# Add Members missing in Group Membership SharePoint online

Tags: permissions, membership

Add Members Option is missing in some of my sites. Do you have suggestions on how can I add it back?

[image]

This is the result that I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the Issue. The owners are in Additional Admins in admin center.  Adding them to Group Owners fix the issue!